# Exchange Account on iPhone Without Unlock Pin

Tags: iphone, exchange-activesync, security

My work exchange account forces me to use an unlock/passcode on my iphone. Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this thread](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=116574) for suggestions for things that you do - but be aware that if your employer has a policy that you shall have a passcode on your phone while connecting to their Exchange server, that it could involve written warnings and possible termination of employment if you are seen to be in contravention of the company's security policies.

Options are:

- Delete the Exchange mail account on the phone
- Buy a beer for your friendly IT dude where you work (always stay friendly with these guys!), and get him to add you as an exclusion to the passcode requirement
- Use a passcode

You should probably always use a passcode anyway, as without one your phone is worth a lot more to a thief (think of all that lovely personal data on there!). If you have an iPhone 5s just set up Touch ID and it's even better.